# How can I use a 'plastic sled'?

Tags: neo-scavenger

I just found an plastic sled in NEO Scavenger.  It's been a while since I've played it, and the developer has been adding shit like crazy, so this is an object I haven't seen before.  On closer inspection it appears to be a 'container' item, which means you can use it to carry other items.  I can't put it in my hands though, or use it in any way right now.  I can't even take it with me since I'm unable to cary it.

Do I need to find a rope or something first?

[image: plastic sled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the sled base with 2x Medium Thread. Once you do you can equip the sled to pull it behind you, carrying more. However you will be unable to run with the sled.

The sled is considered a *vehicle*, so to equip it you need to place it in the vehicle slot.

Comment: Hrm.  I managed to craft it, but I can't figure out how/where to equip it.  Any help?

Comment: Just drop it in the vehicles slot

Comment: Note that it can be placed in the vehicle slot even without thread - it just gives a small movement penalty while equipped in that way.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to placing the sled in the vehicle slot, you can equip the sled by right clicking and selecting Take (unless you already have a vehicle equipped).

Also, the sled can be taken as is (without a strap), but it gives the condition "Pulling sled awkwardly" which is an encumbrance penalty ([source](http://neoscavenger.wikia.com/wiki/Plastic_Sled)).